# Posting a form with hidden fields without submit button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form as

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input name="Descripcion" type="hidden" value="" id="Descripcion" runat="server" />

<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Comprar" />
```

Instead of clicking on submit button i want that the form should be posted without clicking submit button with hidden fields

Comment: How would the form be submitted then? What type of action would be needed?

Comment: Do you need a form, or can you just make an ajax call and get the data to the server that way?

Comment: Your question and example don't make much sense. When do you want this form to be submitted if not when clicking on a button? Also why there's `runat="server"` attribute to your hidden field? This doesn't seem like valid HTML. And third remark, if you are working with ASP.NET WebForms, the single form per page model wouldn't allow you adding additional forms other than the one that's already present and that serves for postbacks.

Comment: If this is going to be run on the server, you might as well do it on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can submit an html form from javascript by calling the form's `.submit()` method.  e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

Of course, you still need an action in your example so the form has somewhere to submit itself to.  Also, you tagged your question `asp.net`.  If this is a webforms page you should use the default form rather then adding your own form to the html markup.  You submit the asp.net form by calling the `__doPostBack()` method.

Answer (score 2):

you can build and submit a form with javascript you can call from other events or when loading a page

```
myform=document.createElement('form');
myform.method='post';
myform.target='_top';
myform.action='';

input1=document.createElement('input'); 
input1.type='hidden'; 
input1.name='Descripcion'; 
input1.value=''; 

myform.appendChild(input1);

document.appendChild(myform);

myform.submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also accomplish the same using jQuery:

```
$('myform').submit();
```