# JavaScript created form not submitting to HTTP Server

Tags: javascript, html, http, webforms, webserver

I have a python server I wrote with a custom do_GET method to parse form values.

My goal is to create a push button that I can put in a table that will notify the server when it was hit and send a unique key that the server can parse. The button only needs to send the pre-programmed key to the server, so there really is no need to have normal form values that the user can input.

I searched on how to do that, and I found this example [Posting a form with hidden fields without submit button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991370/posting-a-form-with-hidden-fields-without-submit-button-click)

I thought this would work well because I could use html to create the pushbutton that would call my JS to submit the "form" to the server.

I click on the button and nothing happens, I looked at my google chrome console and I saw the following error: Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3

I then downloaded firefox and firebug, and firebug stepped through my code fine, but it was my first time using it and I may have overlooked something.

My goal output is to get the server to receive this get request

```
http://172.26.177.17/standardTable.html?TagID=00-00-11-AB-12
```

..or any other message with the value TagID

The entirety of my code is below, you will probably want to change the action to something else, but everything else I think is good.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Test Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function createForm()
    {
    myform=document.createElement('form');
    myform.method='get';
    myform.action='http://172.26.177.17/standardTable.html';

    input1=document.createElement('input');
    input1.type='hidden';
    input1.name='tagID';
    input1.value='00-00-11-AB-12';

    myform.appendChild(input1);
    document.appendChild(myform);
    myform.submit();
    }

</script>

</head>


<body>
<button type="button" onclick="createForm()">Click Me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Change it to document.body.appendChild(myform);

Comment: Put that in an answer and I will give you 25 rep haha (accept + up vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to the document, not the body. You want to append to the body:

```
myform.appendChild(input1);
document.body.appendChild(myform);
myform.submit();
```